# Sending Image (JPG) through Socket in C using raspberry pi and windows

Tags: c

I'm writing a C program in order to be able to transfer  an image file continously between raspberry pi and windows pc computer (from server raspberry pi to client pc) using TCP/IP sockets but there seems to be an error after sending for the  1017th time ,the server quits by stating segmentation fault , i mean in a loop when i intend to send the image file to my client 2000 times the server quits on 1017th image.

server side

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   
#include<unistd.h>  
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<errno.h>

using namespace std;

int send_image(int socket){

    FILE *picture;
    int size, read_size, stat, packet_index;
    char send_buffer[10240], read_buffer[256];
    packet_index = 1;

    picture = fopen("a.jpg", "r");
    printf("Getting Picture Size\n");   

    if(picture == NULL) {
        printf("Error Opening Image File"); 
    }

    fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(picture);
    fseek(picture, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Total Picture size: %i\n",size);

    //Send Picture Size
    printf("Sending Picture Size\n");
    write(socket, (void *)&size, sizeof(int));

    //Send Picture as Byte Array
    printf("Sending Picture as Byte Array\n");

    do { //Read while we get errors that are due to signals.
        stat=read(socket, &read_buffer , 255);
        printf("Bytes read: %i\n",stat);
    } while (stat < 0);

    printf("Received data in socket\n");
    printf("Socket data: %c\n", read_buffer);

    while(!feof(picture)) {
        //while(packet_index = 1){
        //Read from the file into our send buffer
        read_size = fread(send_buffer, 1, sizeof(send_buffer)-1, picture);

        //Send data through our socket 
        do{
            stat = write(socket, send_buffer, read_size);  
        }while (stat < 0);

        printf("Packet Number: %i\n",packet_index);
        printf("Packet Size Sent: %i\n",read_size);     
        printf(" \n");
        printf(" \n");

        packet_index++;  

        //Zero out our send buffer
        bzero(send_buffer, sizeof(send_buffer));
    }
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc , new_socket , c, read_size,buffer = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char *readin;

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8000 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    if((new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client,       (socklen_t*)&c))){
        puts("Connection accepted");
     }

     fflush(stdout);

     if (new_socket<0)
     {
         perror("Accept Failed");
         return 1;
     }
     while(value<2000)
     {
         value =value+1;
         send_image(new_socket);
     }

     close(socket_desc);
     fflush(stdout);
     return 0;
}
```

client side.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<unistd.h>  
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<errno.h>

using namespace std;

//This function is to be used once we have confirmed that an image is to be  sent
//It should read and output an image file

int receive_image(int socket)
{ // Start function 
    int imgc = 0 ; 

    while(imgc < 2000)
    {
        int buffersize = 0, recv_size = 0,size = 0, read_size, write_size,  packet_index =1,stat;

        char imagearray[10240],verify = '1';
        FILE *image;
        int value = 0 ; 
        //Find the size of the image

        value = value + 1;  

        do{
            stat = read(socket, &size, sizeof(int));
        }while(stat<0);

        printf("size = %d" , size) ; 

        if(size>1000)
        {
            imgc = imgc + 1 ; 
            char buffer[] = "Got it";

           //Send our verification signal
           do{
               stat = write(socket, &buffer, sizeof(int));
           }while(stat<0);

           printf("Reply sent\n");
           printf(" \n");

           char fn[100] ; 

           sprintf(fn,"a%d.jpg",imgc);

           image = fopen(fn, "wb"); 

           if( image == NULL) {
               printf("Error has occurred. Image file could not be opened\n");
               return -1; 
           }

           //Loop while we have not received the entire file yet

           int need_exit = 0;
           struct timeval timeout = {10,0};

           fd_set fds;
           int buffer_fd, buffer_out;

           while(recv_size < size) {
               //while(packet_index < 2){
               FD_ZERO(&fds);
               FD_SET(socket,&fds);

               buffer_fd = select(FD_SETSIZE,&fds,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
               if (buffer_fd < 0)
                   printf("error: bad file descriptor set.\n");

              if (buffer_fd == 0)
                  printf("error: buffer read timeout expired.\n");

              if (buffer_fd > 0)
              {
                  do{
                      read_size = read(socket,imagearray, 10240);
                  }while(read_size <0);

                  printf("Packet number received: %i\n",packet_index);
                  printf("Packet size: %i\n",read_size);

                  //Write the currently read data into our image file
                  write_size = fwrite(imagearray,1,read_size, image);
                  printf("Written image size: %i\n",write_size); 

                  if(read_size !=write_size) {
                      printf("error in read write\n");
                  }

                  //Increment the total number of bytes read
                  recv_size += read_size;
                  packet_index++;
                  printf("Total received image size: %i\n",recv_size);
                  printf(" \n");
                  printf(" \n");
              }
          }

          fclose(image);
          printf("Image successfully Received!\n");
       }

   }      
   return 1;
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *parray;


    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    if (socket_desc == -1) {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    memset(&server,0,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.137.137");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8000 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)      {
        cout<<strerror(errno);
        close(socket_desc);
        puts("Connect Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    receive_image(socket_desc);

    close(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, remember that a JPEG file is a *binary* file, it can't be treated like a text file. To continue, you don't send the whole string `"Got it"` as a reply, `sizeof(int) != strlen(buffer)`. Finally, whenever you send or receive strings, remember to *terminate* them.

Comment: On a last note, many of the functions you call can have more errors than you report, and if you get a `read` error on a socket in most cases there's no use in retrying the receive operation (instead you might end up with an infinite `read` loop).

Comment: Note that `ftell()` returns `long`, not `int`.  And `read()`/`write()` return `ssize_t`, not `int`.  There's a reason the functions are defined that way.  Also, read the man page for `sendfile()`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may come from the fact that you use every fd available since you never close any file descriptor and keep opening them. Are you sure you never see the `"Error Opening Image File"` line as an output ? If you do, then you just try to `fseek(NULL)` and that doesn't work too well.

There's a lot of weird stuff going on in your code anyway.

Why do you use `bzero()` over `memset()` ?

Why do you use `printf(%c)` to display a string instead of `printf(%s)`

Edit : Also `using namespace std`; doesn't make much sense in c I think.

Why do you use

```
do{
    stat = write(socket, send_buffer, read_size);  
}while (stat < 0);
```

Meaning you write as long as you have errors. Same goes for read. Also, write may not always write the whole data at once. Which means you need to check if it did.

Why do you keep unused variables such as `verify`.
You should probably use compiling flags to prevent these. If you're using clang or gcc, you could add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compilation line.

You could try to find the bug using valgrind : `valgrind ./your_program your arguments` It would provide you with information about where your program failed. If you use it, be sure to put `-g` in your compilation line to add debug symbols